# How to add 1 for evens in Python?

Tags: python

I'm coming from C++.

Intuitively, in C++, here is what I'd do:

```
int someArray[n];
for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){
   someArray[i] = !(i%2);
}
```

where `i%2 == 0` when `i` is even and `i%2 == 1` when `i` is odd.

The `!` then makes that evens are evaluated as `1` and odds as `0`, so `someArray` would end up with `0` in its odd indices and `1` in its even indices.

This is an example to illustrate what I'd like to do.

Is there a way to do this in Python without the usage of control flow, simply within the mathematical expression itself? `not` evaluates a boolean, and not a `1` or a `0`.

I ask because I am setting the attribute of something `+-1` based on whether a certain `count` is even or odd, and it is nested inside multiple other specifiers.

Comment: It would really help to show and example and desired output. You say you want to **add** 1, but your code looks like it assigns 1. Maybe helpful to consider that `abs(i%2 - 1)` is the opposite of `i%2`? You can also treat `(not (i%2))` as an integer in python.

Comment: Do you consider  `1 if i % 2 == 0 else 0` to be usage of control flow?

Comment: > `not` evaluates a boolean.

This is right. But you could cast this boolean into an integer using `ìnt()`.
Or you go the way with `abs()` as Mark said.

Comment: slightly OT, but if n is not a compile-time constant, then that is not valid c++

Comment: Your C++ code does not assign a value to `someArray[0]`, which leaves the value uninitialized. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @TimbowSix No need to cast, Python booleans are subtypes of integers and can be used like them.

Comment: The underlying question here could be cast as: "what's the operator that turns an integer `1` into `0` and vice versa?" That operator is **bitwise** negation, spelled `~` in Python. Or it could be cast as: "how do I treat a boolean value as an integer?" in which case there is not really a question, because Python implements `bool` as a subtype of `int`. There isn't a **specific, clear** question here, but rather than try to extract one (I don't think it will make a lot of sense) I have provided some reference links to canonical questions on the topic that I think should solve the problem.

Comment: The negation of `0` is `-1` , so that is not wholly accurate @KarlKnechtel . I believe I was looking for the `int` cast.

Comment: Sorry, need more caffeine. `x ^ 1` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly cast the bool to int after adding `not` to the remainder calculation like so:

```py
n = 10 #example length

#list initialization 
some_list = [0]*n

for i in range(n):
    some_list[i] = int(not i%2)
```

You can also make the list a boolean list and use `map` as well.

Here's a [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-convert-boolean-values-to-integer/) to more details on this topic

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `list comprehension` in python.

```
n = 10
some_array = [1 if not i%2 else -1 for i in range(n)]
```

In python `not` operator is used to negate the truthiness of value, not to negate numeric value.

Comment: It's really not worth answering unclear answers here. It doesn't help future users when the question is unclear. For example, I (and presumably future readers) have no idea why you are using `-1` here given the OP's code that could never be `-1`.